# What is length of $AD$ in this triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

I'm preparing for a test and was not able to solve.

Here's the question:

> From the corner $C$ of the triangle $ABC$ draw $CD$, such that $∠ BCD = ∠ BAC$ and $D$ lies on $AB$. Calculate $|AD|$, if $AB = 17$ and $BC = 10$.

That is how the picture may look like:
[image]

We didn't have law of sines or cosines yet. But it can probably be found somewhere so I don't yet know how to use it. From just googling I don't see how this could be solved without the angle even though they are the same.

Now, I tried using the fact that angles are the same could the side lengths also be the same

Nope, that surely can't be as one side is used to make the other, else, it would have to have two sides the same(I don't know how that is called in English)

Comment: Do you have the law of cosines/law of sines?

Comment: I got $\frac{189}{17}.$

Comment: @MichaelBurr angles are not known

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg How?

Comment: @development mentor Show your attempts and I'll show my solution.

Comment: I can't show you anything because I came nowhere. I don't know how to start. Could you please give me a hint.

Comment: @developmentmentor this is a common question and must be on the site somewhere too. The law of sines can surely be applied. Numerical value of angles need not be given for you to solve a problem through law of sines. Are you not given two of the angles in two triangles being the same? You should show your attempt when you post a question.

Comment: @MathLover, We didn't have law of sines or cosines yet. But it can probably be found somewhere so I don't yet know how to use it. From just googling I don't see how this could be solved without the angle even though they are the same.

Comment: Now, I tried using the fact that angles are the same could the side lengths also be the same

Comment: Nope, that surely can't be as one side is used to make the other, else, it would have to have two sides the same(I don't know how that is called in English)

Comment: @developmentmentor I am not saying you have to use law of sines. I said because you responded to a comment saying angles are not given so law of sines cannot be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using law of sines/cosines as suggested in the comments you could use AA similarity between $BCD$ and $BAC$ (they are similar by the statement given and the reflexive property). Call AD x, then BD is $17-x$. From the similar triangles mentioned earlier,
$$\frac{10}{17-x}=\frac{17}{10}$$
Which you can solve to get $x = \frac{189}{17}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me to get the concept clear. Just, may I ask you or anybody reading this to just tell simply, how this could be solved using the law of sines.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AD=x$.

Since $\Delta ACB\sim\Delta CDB$, we obtain:
$$\frac{17-x}{10}=\frac{10}{17},$$ which gives $x=\frac{189}{17}.$

Comment: Thank, you for your answer now I understand. But, I have given the point to the @QED. Because he is a new user while you already have many points.